# PHP Wont send mail

Tags: php, database, email

```
    $name = "http://mafiamakten.com"; //Senderens navn
                $email = "Noreply@http://mafiamakten.com"; //Senderens Email
                $header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields


$recipient = "".$forgotpassword.""; 
$subject = "Nytt passord"; 
$message = "Hei, Ditt nye passord er følgende:
---------------------------- 
Passord: $emailpassword
---------------------------- 
Vennligst vær oppmerksom på denne informasjonen er kryptert i vår database

Denne e-posten ble automatisk sendt."; 
               mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Hi, I have 2 pages. One for registration and one for lost passwords. none of those will work. Does anyone know what is wrong here? Appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: Where is $forgotpassword set? That's apparently who you're sending the email to.

Comment: Have you looked at your logs for errors?

Comment: side note, `Noreply@http://mafiamakten.com` should be `Noreply@mafiamakten.com` i guess

Comment: What does "wont send email" mean? Do you get an error appearing? A blank screen? Does it claim to send the email, but nothing's sent? Is the email appearing in spam? Going to the wrong address? The right address, with the wrong contents?

Comment: Sorry the missleading topicname. it dont give any errors, it calaim to send the email, but im not getting it in my mail. Not in inbox and not in the spam folder.

Answer (score 1):

You're using php's built-in mail() command to send the message.  This sends the message through the local SMTP server running on the same machine where PHP is running.  So, your first step is to check the logs on the local SMTP server.  These should show you, first, whether or not the message was handed off from PHP to the local SMTP server.  Then, if so, the logs should show you what happened when the local SMTP server attempted to deliver the message to the recipient's SMTP server.

If you're not sure of the local SMTP server that PHP is using to send the message, check you php.ini file (or use the phpinfo() command to show your configuration), and look for the sendmail_path setting.  This should show you the command that PHP is using to send the message.  This will most likely be a symbolic link to the sendmail program of the local SMTP server.

Comment: sendmail_from no value no value
sendmail_path /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

that is what ive found

Comment: no value for sendmail_from is fine.  Login to a shell, and do ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail.  Does it show a symbolic link?  If so, to where?